# Write list to 2 different text files

Tags: python

Reading in the data text file,
Running loops to check criteria for valid and invalid student numbers.

Then trying to write 2 text files, one for the invalid student numbers and one for the valid student numbers

This far everything works accept no text files written and no data written to text files at the end

Here is the Script so far

```
inputList = []
outputList = []

def FileOpen(myList):
    #try:
        count=0
        INFILE=open("data.txt", "r")
        for line in INFILE:
            myList.append(line.rstrip())
            count+=1
        INFILE.close()
        return count
    #except:
    #    print("File could not be found")
    #    exit()


FileOpen(inputList)
print(FileOpen(inputList),"number of lines read from file")

def AnalyseStudents(rawStudents,totalStudents):
    for entry in rawStudents:

        amountOfDigits = len(entry)
        testOfDigits = entry.isdigit()

        def inValid1(val1,val2):
            answ = val1 != 8 and val2 != True
            return answ

        inValidResult1=(inValid1(amountOfDigits,testOfDigits))

        def Valid1(val1,val2):
            answ = val1 == 8 and val2 == True
            return answ

        validResult1=(Valid1(amountOfDigits,testOfDigits))

        if inValidResult1:
            print(entry, " is an INVALID student number")

        elif validResult1:
            a=entry[0]
            b=entry[1]
            c=entry[2]
            d=entry[3]
            e=entry[4]
            f=entry[5]
            g=entry[6]
            h=entry[7]
            sum = float((a*8)+(b*7)+(c*6)+(d*5)+(e*4)+(f*3)+(g*2)+(h*1))
            result = sum%11

            def inValid2 (val):
                answ = val != 0
                return answ

            inValidResult2=(inValid2(result))

            def Valid2 (val):
                answ = val == 0
                return answ

            validResult2=(Valid2(result))

            if validResult2:
                print(entry, " is an VALID student number")

            elif inValidResult2:
                print(entry, " is an INVALID student number")

        totalStudents

AnalyseStudents(inputList,outputList)

def Write(outList):
    if outList == (" is an VALID student number"):
        OUTFILE1=open("ValidNumbers.txt","w")
        for validResult in outList:
            OUTFILE1.write(validResult+"\n")
        OUTFILE1.close()
    elif outList == (" is an INVALID student number"):
        OUTFILE2=open("InvalidNumbers.txt","w")
        for inValidResults in outList:
            OUTFILE2.write(inValidResults+"\n")
        OUTFILE2.close()

Write(outputList)
print("See output files for more details")
```

Comment: if you could provide a sample input, it would help a lot instead of guessing the problem with your code.

Comment: All those little 2-line functions make the code *harder* to understand. You should at least separate them out so they don't interrupt the flow of the rest of the code.

Comment: And names like `val1` and `val2` are meaningless.

Comment: Why are you comparing a list with a string? ``outList == (" is an VALID student number"):``

Comment: You never append anything to `totalStudents`. What is it for?

Answer (score 0):

Your equality statements are wrong

```
  if outList == (" is an VALID student number"):
   ...
  elif outList == (" is an INVALID student number"):
```

The `outList` is a list but you are comparing it to strings. Put a debug breakpoint at those `if` statements and decide   what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working my way through this, but for the first function, you can use list comprehension and a couple of other Python functions.  Commentary is included.

```
inputList = []
outputList = []


# Change parameter to the name of the file you want to open.
# Here, we can just make the parameter optional and pass your 
# text file name by default.
def FileOpen(filename="data.txt"):

    # Using with keeps the open file in context until it's finished
    # it will then close automatically.
    with open(filename, "r") as INFILE:
        # Reach all the data at once and then try to decode it.
        data = INFILE.read()
        try:
            data = data.decode("utf-8")

        # If data can't be decoded, then it doesn't have that attribute.
        # Catch that exception
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    # Python 3 has a string method called .splitlines() that makes
    # splitting lines a little simpler.
    myList = [line for line in data.splitlines()]

    # We'll return two values: The length (or count) of the list
    # and the actual list.
    return len(myList), myList

# We set up two variables for intake of our count and list results.
count, myList = FileOpen()
print("{} number of lines read from file".format(count))
```

**EDIT**: I don't know what the last part of your code is aiming to do. Maybe compare student count to valid entries?  Here's the middle part.  I moved the function outside and made it evaluate either valid or invalid in one fell swoop.

```
def is_valid(entry_value):
    """Validate current entry."""
    if len(entry_value) != 8 and entry_value.isnumeric():
        return False
    return True

def AnalyseStudents(rawStudents, totalStudents):

    for entry in rawStudents:

        # Our new function will return True if the entry is valid
        # So we can rework our function to run through the True condition
        # first.
        if is_valid(entry):
            entry_sum = entry[0] * 8
            entry_sum += entry[1] * 7
            entry_sum += entry[2] * 6
            entry_sum += entry[3] * 5
            entry_sum += entry[4] * 4
            entry_sum += entry[5] * 3
            entry_sum += entry[6] * 2
            entry_sum += entry[7] * 1

            if entry_sum % 11 == 0:
                print(entry, " is an VALID student number")

            else:
                print(entry, " is an INVALID student number")

        else:
            print(entry, " is an INVALID student number")



AnalyseStudents(inputList, outputList)
```

Comment: A suggestion was that as a function I made all valid student numbers = 1 and invalid student numbers = 0

Comment: To be able to then use these to assist in writing 2 text files one for all the valid student numbers and one for all the invalid student numbers